# i want to run two scenes in background in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, background, scene

The Problem i'm facing is that i need to run two scenes in background and start the processed working in it that as the the user goes on the desirable scene it will be totally synced and there will be no delay .

i have a login scene when logged in then a dashboard scene will open when the user logs in i want two other scenes to run in the background as the user is on the dashboard scene.

i have tried using some background threads and SceneManager commands but they open the scene and kill the other scenes so when i open the scenes they start from the start what i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

you can have 2 or more scenes open at the same time using the second parameter of [LoadScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) like this:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Comment: Ohk i tried that but i don't think the scenes are running in background because when i open the background scenes by using sceneManager.loadscene  its starting from the start

Comment: no, they arent in the background, they are open at the same time, so you dont need to load them again